# left join for two tables with time based

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am doing accumulation for data, based on 30 minutes  for one day, the customers performed their transactions over this day.
 I have two tables, the first shows the customers behavior in whole day. the second table shows the customer behavior at night only. 
I want to make left join for two tables with time based: 
Is that possible to make? 
Actually, I tried to do that but I got duplication or cross products between two table.

Note: I can make left join between two tables but is not time based.

Here clarification for the tables

Table 1

```
Time_Minutes_Based|User_Id|Total_Of_Transactions|Total_of_outgOing
10:00:30          |   1   |           4         |         9
10:00:30          |   2   |          12         |         5
10:01:30          |   6   |           3         |         2
.                 |       |                     |
.                 |       |                     |
.                 |       |                     |
00:01:30          |   8   |           7         |         3
```

Table 2 for Night Transactions only:

```
Time_Minutes_Based|User_Id|Total_Of_Transactions_at_Night|Total_of_outgoing_at_Night
00:00:30          |   9   |                0             |              6
00:06:30          |   8   |                3             |              3
00:06:30          |   3   |                4             |              0
.                 |       |                              |
.                 |       |                              |
.                 |       |                              |
05:59:00          |   2   |                9             |              3
```

Expected Table:

```
Time_Minutes_Based|User_Id|Total_Of_Transactions|Total_of_outgoing|Time_Minutes_Based|User_Id|Total_Of_Transactions_at_Night|Total_of_outgoing_at_Night 
00:00:30          |  1 |        Null         |      Null       |      Null         |   3   |              1               |
```

Comment: Is there a date field too?

Comment: Yes, but this is going to be one date because these transactions over one day ..

Comment: all night records have the corresponding record in whole day table? or is it possible to find some record in night table that doesn't exists in all day table?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but Time_Minutes_Base of whole day table and NightOnly table must match at 100%.

```
00:00:30 <> 00:00:31


select 
      wd.Time_Minutes_Based
    , wd.User_Id
    , wd.Total_Of_Transactions
    , wd.Total_of_outgOing
    , no.Total_Of_Transactions_at_Night
    , no.Total_of_outgoing_at_Night
from
    WholeDay wd
    left join NightOnly no
where
    wd.UserId = no.UserId
    wd.Time_Minutes_Based = no.Time_Minutes_Based;
```

Another approach if you need to ensure the query returns all records.

```
select 
      Time_Minutes_Based
    , User_Id
    , Total_Of_Transactions
    , wd.Total_of_outgOing
    , ''  as Total_Of_Transactions_at_Night
    , ''  as Total_of_outgoing_at_Night
from
    WholeDay
UNION ALL
select 
      Time_Minutes_Based
    , User_Id
    , '' as Total_Of_Transactions
    , '' as Total_of_outgOing
    , Total_Of_Transactions_at_Night
    , Total_of_outgoing_at_Night
from
    NightOnly;
```